# Magento 2: Meta-keywords and meta-description doesn't appear

Tags: magento2, template, meta-tags, meta, meta-description

I am using a payment template that unfortunately the support has already expired.

`Meta-keywords` and `meta-description` do not appear in the source code. I've assigned to the different websites and products, but nothing, its doesn't appear in the code absolutely anything.

I've been looking for information and I have not found anything.

How can I check if the keywords and description are missing in the template?

How can I add them?

Comment: Run command : php bin/magento cache:flush  and check again

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, even with the cache disabled does not work.

Comment: Rund command :  php bin/magento indexer:reindex and check again

Comment: It has also been tested, in fact a cronjob runs every 5 minutes, thanks.

Comment: Have u install any custom module ? and check is it working with default theme?

Comment: The problem as I said in the post is in the template, sorry, maybe I have not specified it well. If I use the default template they appear correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78770/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-rafael-calero).

Answer (score 1):

I've Installed fresh installation 2.2.2 and There was no Meta description or keywords at all. I you are wondering why there isn't anywhere this is for you!

Got TO Content->Design->configuration edit the first row see the HTML Head: [image]ref:

It was empty! fill those in and you will be able to see the changes you do from your xml, controller etc... otherwise it wont' populate.

hoep it helps

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with a template update patch. Thank you

Comment: Please describe in detail?